# php string comparison not working on ==

Tags: php, string, comparison

i have question on string comparison i have

```
if($decryptedname == $plain)
{
echo "success <br/>";
echo $_SESSION['decryptedname'];
}
```

in a for loop to go through a text file, decryptedname contain a string "Lee" and plain contain the data in my text files and printing line by line, since both of it contain a field with the value "Lee" i assume it should match and print success as well as the $decryptedname but it's not, below is the copy and pasted result, where lee is $decryptedname and those others are echo by $plain thru a for loop

Lee

Decrypted name is Lee

Decrypted email is mjlee181@hotmail.com

Decrypted message is testing

Answer (score 0):

There are chances for whitespace getting added when you load contents from a text file , so in that case always do a `trim()` and then do the comparison.

Like this..

```
if(trim($decryptedname) == trim($plain))
{
echo "success <br/>";
echo $_SESSION['decryptedname'];
}
```

or if you are trying to check if the string contains in another string... you should be doing `stripos()` instead.

```
if(stripos($decryptedname,$plain)!==false)
{
    echo "success <br/>";
    echo $_SESSION['decryptedname'];
}
```

Comment: Can you `var_dump($decryptedname)` and `var_dump($plain)` and post the results ? Also, I think you are looking for the alternate solution I specified in the answer.

Comment: this is what i got for var_dump decrypted name
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"
string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee" string(3) "Lee"

Comment: this is what i got for var_dump $plain 

string(9) "Lee

" string(26) "mjlee181@hotmail.com

" string(13) "testing
"
string(10) "damn

" string(19) "damn@damn.com

" string(10) "damn
"

Comment: As I told you the **whitespace** is the issue. See for `var_dump $plain string(9) "Lee "` It says `string(9)` whereas `var_dump decrypted name string(3) "Lee"` It says 3. _Are you using my code correctly ?_

Comment: $plain = decrypt_string("caesar",$lines[$i],$inc)."<br/>";
if(trim($decryptedname) == trim($plain))
{
echo "success <br/>";
echo $_SESSION['decryptedname'];
}
i put it like this, nothing showed up

Comment: hey @shankar, i got it working, thanks for the input, i found out that it's a new line instead of a whitespace, i know how to replace \n using preg_replace, but how about replace <br/> ?

Comment: Try `strip_tags()` mate. `if(trim($decryptedname) == trim(strip_tags($plain)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
        if (strcasecmp($decryptedname , $plain) == 0) {
            echo "success <br/>";
echo $_SESSION['decryptedname'];
    ?>
```

you can try this .May it help you

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned problem may be caused due to the '\n' present at the end of the string.
If the string "Lee" is present at the end of the line in the text file, it may automatically be appended with '\n' in the end. So if you remove '\n' from the end it might work fine. you can use the following function to do that:

$plain=str_replace("\r\n","",$plain);